# Programmatic report generation for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using MongoDB as database in my web application. I want to have a report generation feature in my application such that the user is presented with the list of available records and fields and he/she selects all or subset of the available fields and then a pdf report is generated containing the data for user selected fields.

Therefore, I need to generate the reports programmatically on run time based on user selected fields. I have found a similar example for mysql [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/).

How should I add the datasource for MongoDB instead of MySQL? Is there any other way of getting this done?

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
report
  .columns(
      Columns.column("Customer Id", "id", DataTypes.integerType()),
      Columns.column("First Name", "first_name",            DataTypes.stringType()),
      Columns.column("Last Name", "last_name", DataTypes.stringType()),
      Columns.column("Date", "date", DataTypes.dateType()))
  .title(Components.text("SimpleReportExample")
      .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
      .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
      .setDataSource("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, date FROM customers",
                              connection);
try {
    report.show();
    report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("c:/report.pdf"));
} catch (DRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you solved your question by now but for other's looking for an answer I responded anyways.
You can use the JRBeanCollectionDataSource(..) for this perpose. Dynamic Reports had created an example how to do that here : http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/collectiondatasourcereport

Simply get your data from MongoDB and load it into a JRBeanCollectionDataSource. Then set it on the report using setDataSource(..)